# How do arrays in Excel translate into R?

Tags: r, excel, csv

I'm trying to transition from using Excel to R, since I've heard it's more efficient especially when it comes to a lot of data; so, I'm pretty new to this all. I'm currently working on figuring out how to have two criterias in sheet 2 to link back to sheet 1, and have it retrieve the average, 25th percentile, 50th percentile, and 75th percentile.

For example, in sheet 2, column B I have a job title "Chief Executive Officer". In sheet 2, column C, I have an asset cut

So, for cell I5 in sheet 2 to be calculated, the formula will go to sheet 1 and look at column E and column AB to make sure it matches sheet 1, column B and C. Then it should take all those values that match in sheet 1, column G and calculate an average.

My current formulas work for excel, but it takes 6 hours to save a change.

I currently have the excel file turned into a csv file.

Here's how it looks in excel form (salaries are $ values, but are "x" for confidentiality reasons):
[sheet 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C73f0.png)
[sheet 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ithQg.png)

Comment: When you say "retrieved average" - what is being retrieved? Can you give some sample data? Overall, this doesn't sound like an array - it sounds like sheet 1 is a dataframe and sheet one are the calculations, and you'll just want to redo those calculations in R based on the data in sheet 1.

Comment: It generally helps if you can narrow the question down to something more specific and provide some excerpts and examples from the actual files. Consider editing the question to include this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in comments, it's hard to guess what you want to achieve and ask based on the information you provided. However, from the screenshots you linked I suppose you have one spreadsheet with registers on base salary and cut of each employee and you want to compute some statistics for base salary grouped by cut and job title.

The data spreadsheet can be imported in R quite easily. I suggest using the "Import Dataset" button in RStudio, which will generate for you the code to import an Excel spreadsheet.

There are several ways to do the computations you need in R. Probably, the simpler one is to use `aggregate` function with something like:

```
aggregate(base_salary, by=list(job_title, cut), mean)
```

That will compute the whole I column (average) in your spreadsheet. For columns J to L (quartiles):

```
aggregate(base_salary, by=list(job_title, cut), quantile, probs=c(.25,.5,.75))
```

Comment: I'm trying to calculate all the values of sheet 2, column i at once though. (It's the equivalent of pulling down a formula in excel rather than typing the formula for each cell, if that helps?) Is this possible with your code above, or do I need to retype it for every single value I'd like to compute?

Comment: You just need to type it once to compute the whole column. In fact, for columns J to L it's even easier because with just one order you can compute all quartiles. A lot of R functions work with whole vectors, and operations on single values are often just a particular case with 1-length vectors. I suggest learning a bit of basic R.